# ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, python-import, importerror, python-module

When trying to import OpenCV, using `import cv2` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 # make IDE's (PyCharm) autocompletion happy
----> 9 from .cv2 import *
     10 
     11 # wildcard import above does not import "private" variables like __version__

ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to fix this - trying to play around with Google's new [Colaboratory](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) tool. Notebook is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7-sJqBiyjCcRmFkMzl6cy1iN0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 185, accepted):

This fixed the problem by having it as the first two lines of the script:

```
!pip install opencv-python
!apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6
!apt-get install -y libxrender-dev
```

Comment: can you elobrate? of which scirpt? cv2/__init__.py?

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron,
`sudo apt-get install libsm6`

Comment: Just sharing so that it may help anybody; I also had to run `sudo apt-get install -y libxrender-dev` to resolve `libXrender` error(which was followed by libsm6)

Answer (score 73):

You need to add sudo . I did the following to get it installed :

```
sudo apt-get install libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1
```

and then did that (optional! maybe you won't need it)

```
sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

FINALLY got it done !

Comment: just using `apt-get install libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1` worked for me

Comment: If you are already a privileged user (such as in a Docker container) you do not need `sudo`, otherwise you do.

Comment: sometime a 32 bit application can be looking for it. In this case do 'sudo apt install libsm6:i386'.

Answer (score 66):

For CentOS, run this:
`sudo yum install libXext libSM libXrender`

Comment: This caused a segfault when running R on the command line as installed by my Anaconda R installation.

Comment: In my case, the 64-bit version was already installed, so I had to use:
`sudo yum install libSM.i686`

Answer (score 48):

There is now a headless version of `opencv-python` which removes the graphical dependencies (like libSM). You can see the normal / headless version on the [releases page](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/releases) (and the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/44) leading to this); just add `-headless` when installing, e.g.,

```sh
pip install opencv-python-headless
# also contrib, if needed
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Comment: I was having error
`ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
once added headless it's gone

Comment: also if anyone looking for a solution to run OpenCV on Google App Engine Flexible environment, this is the solution.

Answer (score 21):

May be the problem is with your `python-opencv` version. It's better to downgrade your version to 3.3.0.9 which does not include any GUI dependencies. Same question was found on GitHub here the link to the [answer](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/90).

Comment: pip install 'opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.9' (after removing the current one, of course: pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python) -https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/44

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem in `docker` and [these steps](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/864#issuecomment-439848887) worked for me:

```
apt update
```

then:

```
apt install libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue with openCV on the `python:3.7-slim` docker box. Following did the trick for me :

```
apt-get install build-essential libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
```

Please see if this helps !

Comment: @SaurabhGupta Thanks, you are right. Just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to install cv2 on Anaconda-Jupyter notebook running on Ubuntu on Google Cloud Platform. But I found a way to do it as follows:

Run the following command from the ssh terminal and follow the instruction:

```
 sudo apt-get install libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1
```

Once its installed Open the Jupyter notebook and run following command:

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Note: I tried to run this command: "sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python"but it was showing an error. But above command worked for me.

Now refresh the notebook page and check whether it's installed or not by running `import cv2` in the notebook.

Comment: I also had to add `apt install libxext6`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using heroku, follow these steps:

add a file named Aptfile in your repo
and include a list of apt package names to be installed in that Aptfile

something like this in (my case)

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

now try pushing the code to heroku. This will do the job.

Or you can still refer this [blog](https://blog.jcharistech.com/2020/02/26/how-to-deploy-a-face-detection-streamlit-app-on-heroku/)

Comment: Can you try to include the contents of the Aptfile with the case of the question instead or your case?

Comment: I was getting the same error, the reason of this error is the following packages aren't included with opencv package. So these are to be installed explicitly. I guess the same contents will do the job to resolve the question also.

Comment: If the packages are to be installed explicitly every time after deployment in new server its best way we add Aptfile and place the contents in it. Rather using cli and apt - get install.