# Use OpenCV on deployed Flask app (Heroku)

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, web-deployment

Hello I seem to be having trouble importing opencv on my deployed flask app on Heroku!

I've referred to similar posts such as this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)
"ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory " but can't seem to figure out the next steps on windows.

This is what I've done so far:
1. gone to Heroku -> App -> Settings -> Buildpacks -> added Python buildpack
2. Added a Aptfile.txt to my directory with the following packages on each line (read this somewhere not sure if it makes any sense)

libsm6 , libxrender1 ,libfontconfig1, libice6

Notes:

- My openCV version--  opencv-python==3.4.3.18
- I'm on windows so the sudo commands recommended in the other post answers dont work

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Use opencv-python-headless it's out of libSM6 dependency.

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Answer (score 3):

put this line in requirments.txt

> opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32