# How to import cv2 for Python in a docker (Azure Web App)?

Tags: python, azure, docker, opencv

The error that is displayed is:

```
...
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491189686Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491192986Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491196286Z     __import__(module)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491199486Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/Webapp/main.py", line 12, in 
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491203086Z     import cv2
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491206386Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in 
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491209886Z     from .cv2 import *
2019-08-16T11:48:08.491213086Z ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2019-08-16T11:48:08.497759820Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [36] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 36)
2019-08-16T11:48:08.652109211Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [33] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-08-16T11:48:08.652493413Z [2019-08-16 11:48:08 +0000] [33] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I found resources online that say I need to run ([ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo))

But on the Azure Platform, once the deployment isnt running, it isnt possible to connect to the web SSH. So how do I fix this issue of importing cv2?
 [image: Web SSH attempt]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the dependency package to proper install and also it needs the scikit-image==0.15.0

pip install opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-python