# Django OpenCV Exception Value: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, opencv, heroku

I am trying to deploy my simple OpenCV based app to Heroku. The app capture live stream only from webcam. My App worked well in the local environment while it gives the following error on Heroku platform.

```
Exception Value: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve it?

**EDIT:**
It is not possible to capture live streams using OpenCV on the server. Because the server itself doesn't have a physical camera to be picked by OpenCV. For this purpose, we need javascript functionality to use our local camera by the server.  This [Github repo](https://github.com/talhaanwarch/facedetect) can  be a good starting point

But this particular error can be resolved using `pip install opencv-python-headless` instead of `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) of any help?

Comment: Edits addded @AzyCrw4282

Comment: reply took a while, almost a year to be precise! I am currently busy with other stuff so can only look into answering these when i am free. If you are in need of urgent solution, I'd recommend reposting this question.