# ImportError: libICE.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

I know it has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) but the answer didn't helped me.

I installed via pip opencv-python imported it and obviously used it and on my local machine everything works. Then I pushed the code on heroku and this error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 7, in <module>
from pre_img import process_image
File "/app/pre_img.py", line 3, in <module>
import cv2
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libICE.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
flask
pytesseract
opencv-python
```

And this is my Aptfile:

```
tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr-all
libsm6
libxext6
libxrender-dev
python-qt4
```

What can I do to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I modified the Aptfile from:

```
tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr-all
libsm6
libxext6
libxrender-dev
python-qt4
```

to:

```
tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr-all
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```