# import error when using packages of python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

Can some one please help me with this error. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and jupyter notebook. (I have directly installed project jupyter from ubuntu app store. I don't have anaconda installed with it or spyder.)

I have tried following but nothing worked at

```
!pip install opencv-python

sudo apt-get install python3-opencv

apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
```

Strange thing is if write the same code in other python file and run it through terminal it's working. But I am unable to run the same code in Jupyter Notebook

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

/home/adarsh/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
      3 import sys
      4 
----> 5 from .cv2 import *
      6 from .data import *
      7 

ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried updated and install the libraries? `apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev`

Comment: @CarlosDutra Yes I have tried that too.

Comment: Can you check which python you use in the terminal an which one you use in your ipython notebook?

Comment: may i see your cv2 file ??? Just try with space 

from .(dot)<space>cv2 import *

Comment: @Marc Both terminal and jupyter notebook are using python 3

Comment: Do they point to exactly the same one?

Comment: @SumitYadav I am getting this while trying your method


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.cv2'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: It says No Such File Directory, which means it is unable to find the CV2 file

Comment: @Marc Will you please tell me how can I know whether they are pointing to the same one or not please..

Comment: @SumitYadav Then what can I do to get rid of this ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)

Comment: Instead of using cv2 twice try this

--> from cv2 import *

Comment: @SumitYadav from cv2 import * didn't worked either , i am getting the same error again

Comment: @qWx I have tried it too. But the error still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below lines infront of my code solved my problem

```
!pip install opencv-python-headless
# also contrib, if needed
!pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use
jupyter notebook itself to install

```
conda install opencv
```

Comment: it's not working either, but thanks for you concern. Can you tell me if there is any other way to get rid of this error please..........

Comment: i will see if i get anything else!!

Comment: i have written it in notebook

Comment: sorry bro but this is what i know to my best !!..hope you get the solution

Comment: why are you sorry bro, you have tried your best to solve this error even though it is not your problem. I am really thankful to get in contact with such nice people