# Flask APP on Azure is giving import cv2 ImportError: libGL.so.1: after deployment

Tags: azure, opencv, flask, web-applications

I have a flask-app that contains some OpenCV methods, I tested it locally and it's working fine, then I deployed this app to Azure using a web app and it successfully deployed, but when I hit the given URL then this error is showing on the browser:

> :( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can
> access the diagnostic resources.

and when I check the log file then this error is being shown:

> from cv2 import * ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory

Comment: I resolved it using these commands: apt-get update , 
apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -

Answer (score 1):

1. In `requirements.txt` use `opencv-python-headless==4.5.1.48` instead of `opencv-contrib-python==4.5.1.48`.
2. If the above method does not work, build a custom docker image on top of AML base images(i.e. mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base-gpu:0.2.4) and include the mesa's GL library in conda using `conda_packages=['mesa-libgl-cos6-x86_64']`

This is related to this [ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113029/importerror-libsm-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)